# Пагинация для комментариев в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

```html
<?php
if (post_password_required()) {
 return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

 <?php
 if (have_comments()) : ?>
  <?php 
  function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth){
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
   <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <div class="col-12">
      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
       <em>Ваш комментарий ожидает проверки.</em>
       <br />
      <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-3 comment-avatar">
      <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $size='100'); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-9">
      <div class="comment-name"><?php echo get_comment_author_link()?> <span class="comment-date"><?php printf( '%1$s в %2$s', get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></span></div>
      <div class="comment-text">
       <?php comment_text() ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  <ul class="comment-list">
   <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=mytheme_comment&per_page=3'); ?>
  </ul>
  
  <div>
  <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?>
  <?php the_comments_pagination( array(
   'prev_text' => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
   'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
  ));?></div>
  
  <?php

 endif; // Check for have_comments().

 $defaults = array(
 'fields' => array(
  'author' => '<div class="form-group row">' . '<label for="author" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">' . __( 'Name' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
  '<div class="col-sm-6"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" class="form-control" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . $html_req . ' /></div></div>',
  'email'  => '<div class="form-group row"><label for="email" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">' . __( 'Email' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
  '<div class="col-sm-6"><input id="email" name="email" class="form-control"' . ( $html5 ? 'type="email"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" aria-describedby="email-notes"' . $aria_req . $html_req  . ' /></div></div>',
 ),
 'comment_field'        => '<div class="form-group row"><label for="comment" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label> <div class="col-sm-6"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5"  aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></div></div>',
 'label_submit' => 'Отправить',
 'submit_field' => '<div class="submit-margin form-group text-center">%1$s %2$s</div>',
 'class_submit' => 'btn btn-black',
 );

  comment_form( $defaults );
 ?>
</div><!-- #comments -->
```

```
the_comments_navigation()
the_comments_pagination();
paginate_comments_links();
```

Выводят пустой блок. Подскажите что не так?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все эти функции прямо или косвенно в своем коде используют проверку

```
if ( ! is_singular() )
    return;
```

Полагаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь их использовать не при отображении отдельного поста, а на какой-то странице архивов.

Comment: Да, это отдельная страница. Как мне быть в этом случае?

Comment: Не знаю. Проверка производится в функциях ядра WordPress. Править ядро - последнее дело. Вывод - не использовать эти функции на тех страницах сайта, которые не удовлетворяют условию is_singular

Comment: Проверил. В постах не работает так же

Comment: как называется файл, из которого дан пример кода, где он расположен?

Comment: comments.php в корне с папкой темы

Answer (score 2):

Нужно зайти в Настройки обсуждения и поставить флажок на:
"Разбивать комментарии верхнего уровня на стран...."
И все вышеперечисленные функцию начнут работать....